# Tombs of Mattathias and Sons

Tags: history, old-testament, jews, 1-maccabees

From 1 Maccabees 13:25–30:

> Simon sent and recovered the bones of his brother Jonathan, and
> ***buried him in Modein***, the town of his ancestors.
>
> All Israel kept solemn mourning for him and long bewailed him.
>
> Over the tomb of his father and brothers, Simon raised a monument high
> enough to catch the eye, using dressed stone back and front.
>
> ***He erected seven pyramids facing each other***, for his father and mother and his four brothers, surrounding them with a structure consisting of tall columns surmounted by trophies of arms to their everlasting memory and, beside
> the trophies of arms, ships sculpted on a scale to be seen by all who
> sail the sea.
>
> Such was the monument he constructed at Modein, and it is still there
> today.

Wikipedia provides an image of Tomb of Mattathias:

[image: Tomb attributed of Mattathias]

But, it doesn't say anything about the authenticity of the tomb or seven pyramids.

- Are these seven pyramids still there?
- Are there any studies conducted regarding this?